# How do I implement inout port into interface and connect to DUT?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to implement an inout port into an interface and connect it to DUT.

This is the original DUT.

```
module mem_ram (
  clk     , // clock input                                               
  cs      , // chip select                                               
  a_we    , // channel A write enable                                    
  a_oe    , // channel A output enable                                   
  a_addr  , // channel A address                                         
  a_data  , // channel A inout data                                      
  b_we    , // channel B write enable                                    
  b_oe    , // channel B output enable                                   
  b_addr  , // channel B address                                         
  b_data    // channel B inout data                                      
);

    // Setup some parameters                                             
    parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8;  // word size of the memory                
    parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 17;//8;  // number of memory words, e.g. 2^8-1
    parameter RAM_DEPTH  = 1 << ADDR_WIDTH;                              
                                                                         
    // Define inputs                                                     
    input clk,  cs;                                                      
    input a_we, a_oe, b_we, b_oe;                                        
    input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] a_addr, b_addr;                               
                                                                         
    // Data is bidirectional
    inout [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] a_data;                                       
    inout [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] b_data;

    ...
    ...

   assign a_data = (a_oe && cs && !a_we)? r_data : 8'bz;
   assign b_data = (b_oe && cs && !b_we)? r_data : 8'bz;
endmodule
```

This is the original testbench:

```
module tb_mem_ram();

    // Define our controlled signals
    reg clk=0;
    reg cs=0;
    reg a_we, a_oe, b_we=0, b_oe=1;
    wire [7:0] a_data;     // this is the connection to ramcu data port
    reg [7:0] a_addr=0;     // this is the address for port A
    wire [7:0] b_data;     // this is the connection to ramcu data port
    reg [7:0] b_addr=0;     // this is the address for port A

    reg  [7:0] a_data_value; // need a register to store value to send on a write
    reg  [7:0] b_data_value; // need a register to store value to send on a write
   
    // Instantiate our DUT
    mem_ram dut (
        clk     , // clock input
        cs      , // chip select
        a_we    , // channel A write enable
        a_oe    , // channel A output enable
        a_addr  , // channel A address
        a_data  , // channel A inout data
        b_we    , // channel B write enable
        b_oe    , // channel B output enable
        b_addr  , // channel B address
        b_data    // channel B inout data
);

assign a_data = !a_oe ? a_data_value : 'bz;
assign b_data = !b_oe ? b_data_value : 'bz;
...
endmodule
```

To connect between DUT and testbench, I implemented an interface as below:

```
   interface mem_intf();
        
    logic   clk    ;
    logic   cs     ;
    logic   a_we   ;
    logic   a_oe   ;
    logic   [16:0]  a_addr ;                      
    logic   [7:0]   a_data ;                      
    wire    [7:0]   a_data_w ;
    logic   b_we   ;
    logic   b_oe   ;
    logic   [16:0]  b_addr ;
    logic   [7:0]   b_data ;
    wire    [7:0]   b_data_w ;
        
    assign a_data_w = a_data;
    assign b_data_w = b_data;
        
    endinterface
```

and I revised as below:

mem.sv

```
module mem_ram (
mem_intf intf
);

    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] mem [0:RAM_DEPTH-1]; 
    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] r_data;               
    reg r_a_oe;                                                  
    reg r_b_oe;                                                                             
    
    always@ (posedge intf.clk) begin                                     
        if (intf.cs) begin                                               
            if (intf.a_we)                                               
                mem[intf.a_addr] <= intf.a_data;                         
            if (intf.b_we)                                               
                mem[intf.b_addr] <= intf.b_data;                         
            r_data <= mem[intf.a_addr];                                  
        end
       r_a_oe   <= intf.a_oe;
        r_b_oe   <= intf.b_oe;
    end

    // arrange outputs
    assign intf.a_data = (intf.a_oe && intf.cs && !intf.a_we)? r_data : 8'bz;
    assign intf.b_data = (intf.b_oe && intf.cs && !intf.b_we)? r_data : 8'bz;
endmodule
```

and tb top.sv is

```
interface mem_intf(input clk);

//logic clk    ;
logic   cs     ;
logic   a_we   ;
logic   a_oe   ;
logic   [16:0]  a_addr ;
logic   [7:0]   a_data ;
wire    [7:0]   a_data_w ;
logic   b_we   ;
logic   b_oe   ;
logic   [16:0]  b_addr ;
logic   [7:0]   b_data ;
wire    [7:0]   b_data_w ;

assign a_data_w = a_data;
assign b_data_w = b_data;

endinterface


module tb_mem_ram;
bit clk;
always #5 clk = ~clk;

    mem_intf intf(clk);
   reg  [7:0] a_data_value; // need a register to store value to send on a write
   reg  [7:0] b_data_value; // need a register to store value to send on a write
    
    // Instantiate our DUT
    mem_ram dut (
  intf
);

assign intf.a_data = !intf.a_oe ? a_data_value : 'bz;
assign intf.b_data = !intf.b_oe ? b_data_value : 'bz;

initial begin
...
end
 assign b_data_value = intf.a_data;
...
endmodule
```

When I compile this, I got error messages:

```
 Variable 'tb_mem_ram.intf.a_data' has multiple conflicting drivers and the indicated continuous assignment in scope 'tb_mem_ram.dut' is contributing to this conflict set.
assign intf.a_data = !intf.a_oe ? a_data_value : 'bz;
                   
 Variable 'tb_mem_ram.intf.a_data' has multiple conflicting drivers and the indicated continuous assignment in scope 'tb_mem_ram' is contributing to this conflict set.
    assign intf.b_data = (intf.b_oe && intf.cs && !intf.b_we)? r_data : 8'bz;
```

If I commented them, the compile passed, but `inout` port does not work.
How do I implement `inout` port into interface and connect to DUT?

Complete example in https://edaplayground.com/x/GCYA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the compile errors, change `logic` to `wire` in the `mem_intf` interface:

```
wire [7:0]   a_data ;
wire [7:0]   b_data ;
```

`wire` is a net type, which supports multiple tri-state drivers.